# Minimize button and context help button in the same title bar in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

To make a help button in the title bar in a Qt window of the type QWidget, I do like this:

```
myWindow->setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint);
```

This works fine.

To make a minimize button in the title bar in the same kind of window, I do like this:

```
myWindow->setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint);
```

This also works fine.

What I want to do is to have both a help button and a minimize button in the title bar of same window. For that, I tried to combine the flags:

```
myWindow->setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint);
```

This only shows the minimize button, not the help button (at least in Windows). How do I show both buttons in the same title bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is impossible on windows. Here is why:

- `Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint` is implemented by adding [`WS_MINIMIZEBOX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx#WS_MINIMIZEBOX) window style, see [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/plugins/platforms/windows/qwindowswindow.cpp?h=5.7#n595).
- `Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint` is implemented by adding [`WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx#WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP) extended window style, see [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/plugins/platforms/windows/qwindowswindow.cpp?h=5.7#n601).

From the reference for [`WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx#WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP):

> `WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP` cannot be used with the `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX` or
>   `WS_MINIMIZEBOX` styles.

So, you can never have a window with the minimize button [ - ] and the context help button [ ? ] on windows.

If you really want to do so, you may have to use a frameless window, and provide your own custom frames.

**Note:** This answer is about windows platform only.